# TypeError: Consumer key must be string or bytes, not NoneType - Twitter Bot

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to make a bot that keeps waiting for new tweets that contain certain keywords so that the bot likes and retweets them and I found a template code that seemed very good to me but it doesn't work for me, I don't know if it's because I have a updated version of Tweepy, could you help me please? This is the code of the bot and the config file:

**BOT.py:**

```
import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api
import json

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

class FavRetweetListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        self.me = api.me()

    def on_status(self, tweet):
        logger.info(f"Processing tweet id {tweet.id}")
        if tweet.in_reply_to_status_id is not None or \
            tweet.user.id == self.me.id:
            # This tweet is a reply or I'm its author so, ignore it
            return
        if not tweet.favorited:
            # Mark it as Liked, since we have not done it yet
            try:
                tweet.favorite()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav", exc_info=True)
        if not tweet.retweeted:
            # Retweet, since we have not retweeted it yet
            try:
                tweet.retweet()
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error("Error on fav and retweet", exc_info=True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        logger.error(status)

def main(keywords):
    api = create_api()
    tweets_listener = FavRetweetListener(api)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweets_listener)
    stream.filter(track=keywords, languages=["es"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(["Anyting", "Anityng"])
```

**config.py:**

```
import tweepy
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()

def create_api():
    consumer_key = os.getenv("KEY")
    consumer_secret = os.getenv("KEY")
    access_token = os.getenv("KEY")
    access_token_secret = os.getenv("KEY")

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

**When i try to run the bot this is the text in my terminal:**
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOokn.png)

Comment: It seems like you need to specify consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token and access_token_secret. You can insert the values directly into the code or by any other means.

Comment: Which line throws the error? Please try and isolate your problem

Comment: I added a screenshot of my terminal

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying all your credentials as the same `KEY` environment variable, which seems to not be defined.

Comment: I removed the credentials to publish the question bro, in my code if I have them defined

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You don't have the environment variable defined. `consumer_key` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo, not sure if you were able to solve this yet, but I'll provide a solution since no-one else did. As mentioned by @harmon758, you haven't specified where your .env file is stored.

A workaround to this can be to use the [dotenv plugin](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). Make sure that your .env file is stored in your root folder, then initialise the function as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having the same problem returning null value form my keys, but i didn't notice that in my .env file, instead of being like:

```
API_KEY='mykey'
```

was like:

```
API_KEY:'mykey'
```

try to verify if your keys are correct declared, maybe this should work.